# Unable to perform join after repartition of pyspark data frame

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark

We are joining two huge files.

So we are trying to repartition on key column
and then we are trying to join on the key column.

**Code snippet**

```
def repartition_df(df,primary_key,partition_value):
    df = df.repartition(partition_value,primary_key)


df_1 = repartition_df(df1,'pk1', 4 )
df_2 = repartition_df(df2,'pk1', 4 )

df3 = df_1.join(df_2,on =  ['pk1'] , how = 'left')
```

**Error message**

```
An error was encountered:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'join'
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'join'
```

**When it works :**

Now, if i dont repartion and go ahead with the join, it works fine.

But from performance perspective, we would like to join after repartition

Can you please let me know, how do I proceed.

Comment: you missed the return, just do return df in your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `return` statement and your solution will work just fine.

```
def repartition_df(df, primary_key, partition_value):
    df = df.repartition(partition_value, primary_key)
    return df

df_1 = repartition_df(df1, 'pk1', 4)
df_2 = repartition_df(df2, 'pk1', 4)

df3 = df_1.join(df_2, on=['pk1'], how='left')
```